# Ускорить код. Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

Коллеги, как можно ускорить данный код? Логика работы: Функция должна видоизменять массив таким образом, чтобы каждый индекс имел одинаковое количество значений. Вход [0,10]> Выход [5,5]

В данном исполнении получаю Execution Timed Out (12000 ms)

Необходимо вернуть не новый лист, а изменить имеющийся.

```
def redistribute_wealth(wealth):
    result =  [sum(wealth)/len(wealth) for x in wealth]
    wealth.clear()
    for i in range(len(result)):
        wealth.append(result[i])
    return wealth
```

Answer (score 5):

Если нужно именно изменить, то нужно менять по месту:

```
def redistribute_wealth(wealth):
    average =  sum(wealth)/len(wealth)
    for i in range(len(wealth)):
        wealth[i] = average
    return wealth
```

Answer (score 4):

Ваш код легко сокращается до такого:

```py
def redistribute_wealth(wealth):
    return [sum(wealth)/len(wealth)] * len(wealth)
```

Если и этого будет по скорости не хватать, то можно перейти на массивы библиотеки `Numpy`. Единственное, что мне непонятно - зачем вам массив одинаковых значений на выходе? Это же заведомо будут одинаковые числа, зачем их плодить и тратить память? Вы можете как-то воспользоваться этим знанием, что они одинаковые.

Comment: То что исходный список модифицируется - ерунда, на общую производительность не сильно влияет по идее (это по заданию нужно, но правда тогда return не должно быть). Вот то что сумма n раз вычисляется - это проблема, уже из-за этой суммы алгоритм из линейного в квадратичный превращается.

Comment: Твое решение вернет копию листа, а не изменит старый. Если я, конечно, не ошибаюсь. Необходимо именно изменить исходный лист.

Comment: @chernyahovsky2010 Так присвойте результат выполнения этому самому листу ;)

Comment: @chernyahovsky2010 Если это обязательное условие, то да, новый список не подходит. Но питонический подход - это всё же делать новый список :)  Обычно никакой разницы нет и возиться со старым списком - это только лишние дополнительные хлопоты, новый список создать обычно проще.

Comment: CrazyElf, согласен

Comment: по мне этот ответ самый правильный, из замечаний выделить размер списка и среднее значение в переменные, чтобы не считать их несколько раз

Comment: @ЭдуардИзмалков Так сумма у меня считается один раз, а длина списка записана в свойствах списка и берётся без подсчётов, её нет смысла сохранять в переменной.

Answer (score 2):

ну если такое условие, то можно так испитониться:

```
from statistics import mean

def redistribute_wealth(wealth):
    wealth[::] = [mean(wealth)]*len(wealth)
    return

w = [0,10]

redistribute_wealth(w)
print(w)  # [5, 5]
```

Answer (score 2):

Заменить значения по месту без выделения дополнительной памяти и циклов:

```
def redistribute_wealth(wealth):
    average = sum(wealth) / len(wealth)
    wealth[:] = (average for _ in range(len(wealth)))


wealth = list(range(10))
print(id(wealth), wealth)
redistribute_wealth(wealth)
print(id(wealth), wealth)
```

> ```
> $ python redistribute_wealth.py
> 140063750132736 [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
> 140063750132736 [4.5, 4.5, 4.5, 4.5, 4.5, 4.5, 4.5, 4.5, 4.5, 4.5]
> ```